# synchronized or select ... for update, incremention of an entity's field

Tags: java, sql

I need to implement an incremental function on an entity stored in DB (we use Hibernate). I try to find the better way for such an operation. Is that using `synchronyzed()` or SQL query?
I have this code:

```
Question q = answer.getQuestion();
Vote v = new Vote();
v.setUser(user);
v.setAnswer(answer);
v.setRightAnswer(answer.isRightAnswer());
v.setQuiz(q.getQuiz());
v.setQuestion(q);
v.setPoints(answer.getPoints());

synchronized (lock) {
  q.setVotes(q.getVotes() + 1);
}

save(v);
questionDao.save(q);
```

It's from DAO class's method, lock is `private final Object` field in that class.

Comment: Always DB, within a Transaction.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html